# React protect the website with password

Tags: reactjs, cookies, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm building the website that needs to start with JUST the password protected page - there is one universal password and no username. After the password has been submitted, you get transferred to the welcome page. There is no database, so I need to store the password input in the cookies somehow. What's the best way to approach the build? I'm still trying to figure out two things:

1. how to restrict the page to /login route when there is no password cookie present
2. create a component that would ask the password, confirm that it's correct and transfer the route from /login to /home and store it in the cookies.

Comment: I don't see how what you're describing can work You need to either store something in a database on the server side or use an external service. Either way, you must have something to authenticate against. Only other thing you could do is hard-code the user names and passwords.

Comment: Sorry I've corrected my ask - there is one universal password - it will be used internally by a company so they need to have just one password that their employees will have access to. There are no various usernames/logins .

Comment: Without a server or external service you would need to hardcode the one universal password into your javascript which is not secure because anyone who knows how to open the browser dev tools could login. You are better off using a 3rd party solution and using a username and password. You could use firebase https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web, auth0 https://auth0.com/, or AWS Cognito https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/

Comment: Why don't you just use .htaccess to password protect it? It's not exactly what you say you want, but should be good enough for your use case as it will deny any access to the site for anyone without the right username and password.